# MongoDB ignoring $push command wihout errors | Python

Tags: python, mongodb

I have the document with array field and 1st value in it.

I want to update this document and add the value in array, so I get the document by find_one command and use this code:

```
mg[db][collection].update_one(document, {"$push": {array_field: value} })
mg.close()
print("end")
```

So, I can see the "end" print, but when I check mongo I realize that my array still has only 1 value and it wasn't update.

I tried to make the new array and update document with $set, but same problem break it up

No errors, what's wrong?

P.S. all other mongodb methods works fine with all documents except of this array-field

**==========**

Update:

I have db **"chanlist"** and collection **"channels"** with document:

```
{
                "name": "FilmNews",
                "chat_link": "filmnewsss",
                "chat_id": 1283929492,
                "repost_ids": [1395174524],
}
```

I need to add **1351487118** in **"repost_ids"**, so my steps are:

```
# db = chanlist db

x = db.channels.find_one({"name": "FilmNews"})

db.channels.update_one(x,  {"$push": {"repost_ids": 1351487118 } })

db.close()

print("check")
```

I did it all, seeing "check" print in my console, going to cloud.mongodb.com, updating page and my document still is:

```
{
                    "name": "FilmNews",
                    "chat_link": "filmnewsss",
                    "chat_id": 1283929492,
                    "repost_ids": [1395174524],
}
```

Its not updated...

Comment: Please post the document affected both before and after the update.

Comment: @Joe Drumgoole, before:

`{name: "FilmNews",

"chat_link" : "filmnewsss",

"chat_id": 1283929492,

"repost_ids": [ 1395174524 ]}`

after:

`{name: "FilmNews",

"chat_link" : "filmnewsss",

"chat_id": 1283929492,

"repost_ids": [ 1395174524 ]}`

Comment: What is the filter `document`?

Comment: @Joe Drumgoole, This is an item that I got by find_one method

Answer (score 0):

I followed all your steps and the `update_one` worked just fine for my in both Python and the mongo shell. I include the shell example below:

```
> db.test.insert({name: "FilmNews",  "chat_link" : "filmnewsss",  "chat_id": 1283929492,  "repost_ids": [ 1395174524 ]})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.test.findOne({name: "FilmNews"})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5edec43e290fc9eea2bb5e4a"),
    "name" : "FilmNews",
    "chat_link" : "filmnewsss",
    "chat_id" : 1283929492,
    "repost_ids" : [
        1395174524
    ]
}
> x=db.test.findOne({name: "FilmNews"})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5edec43e290fc9eea2bb5e4a"),
    "name" : "FilmNews",
    "chat_link" : "filmnewsss",
    "chat_id" : 1283929492,
    "repost_ids" : [
        1395174524
    ]
}
> db.test.updateOne(x,  {"$push": {array_field: 1 } })
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }
> db.test.findOne({name: "FilmNews"})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5edec43e290fc9eea2bb5e4a"),
    "name" : "FilmNews",
    "chat_link" : "filmnewsss",
    "chat_id" : 1283929492,
    "repost_ids" : [
        1395174524
    ],
    "array_field" : [
        1
    ]
}
>
```

Here is the same code in the shell so it matches your example exactly:

```
> db.test.drop()
true
> db.test.insert({name: "FilmNews",  "chat_link" : "filmnewsss",  "chat_id": 1283929492,  "repost_ids": [ 1395174524 ]})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> x = db.test.findOne({name: "FilmNews"})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ef1c348bfa1a5850c9399aa"),
    "name" : "FilmNews",
    "chat_link" : "filmnewsss",
    "chat_id" : 1283929492,
    "repost_ids" : [
        1395174524
    ]
}
> db.test.updateOne(x,  {"$push": {array_field: 1 }})
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }
> db.test.findOne({name: "FilmNews"})
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ef1c348bfa1a5850c9399aa"),
    "name" : "FilmNews",
    "chat_link" : "filmnewsss",
    "chat_id" : 1283929492,
    "repost_ids" : [
        1395174524
    ],
    "array_field" : [
        1
    ]
}
>
```

Comment: As 'array_field' I mean 'repost_ids' field, which I want to update, sorry
So I need to add new value in 'repost_ids'

Comment: change the `$push` to `{$push :  { reposts_id : <value> }}

Comment: Yes, I have it in my original code and I have this problem with ignoring update method
"array_field" and "document" are just pseudo-code elemets for easy show my operations

Comment: Are you updating one document and looking at another with the same contents?

Comment: No, I'm using update method with $push, but document not updated and I have no errors or warnings

Comment: So, just for test I tried to update document like you: `db.test.updateOne(x,  {"$push": {array_field: 1 } })`
It should add a new array "array_field" with value "1", but it didn't

And the same situation - no errors or warnings, but I can see the "end" print

Comment: What version of MongoDB? What driver? What version of the driver?

Comment: python 3.7.3 and pymongo 3.10.1

Comment: MongoDB? The server version?

Comment: MongoDB I think 4.2.6 and server GCP / Belgium europe-west1 (?) or what you mean 'server version?'

Comment: Added a Mongo Shell example. I still can't see the problem you are seeing. Can you post a complete example of your problem in the original question rather than a code fragment?

Comment: Can you make it a complete working example? code fragments are not enough. I need to see how you are connecting and how you are creating the collection and database.

Comment: Collection and database was created in browser on cloud.mongodb.com and connection looks like 
`db = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb+srv://admin:*password*@clustername-aatt2.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority")`